# Android : Trouble with query containing apostrophe

Tags: android, apostrophe

I am trying to run a query for my media player as follows:

```
audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, 
      AlbumColumns.ALBUM + "='" + albumKey + "'", null,AudioColumns.TRACK + " ASC");
```

A problem arises when the album has an apostrophe in it, as it ends the albumKey segment and errors out.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You,
Josh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the question mark. You should **always** do that when using strings.

```
audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, 
    AlbumColumns.ALBUM + "=?",
    new String[] { albumKey },
    null,
    AudioColumns.TRACK + " ASC");
```

Comment: No problem! If you have multiple strings, use multiple question marks, and add them in the same order to that string array.